# Remove duplicate with lower Date from SQL result

Tags: postgresql

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Kundendaten (
beschreiben_knr INTEGER REFERENCES Kunde(knr) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
erstelldatum DATE,
anschrift VARCHAR(40),
sonderrabat INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (erstelldatum, beschreiben_knr)
);
```

If i make this query:

```
select * from Kundendaten ORDER BY erstelldatum DESC;
```

i get:

```
 beschreiben_knr | erstelldatum |   anschrift   | sonderrabat 
-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------
               1 | 2015-11-01   | Winkelgasse 5 |           0
               2 | 2015-11-01   | Badeteich 7   |          10
               3 | 2015-11-01   | Senfgasse 7   |          15
               1 | 2015-10-30   | Sonnenweg 3   |           5
```

But i need to get only the entry for the highest date entry if there are more then one. In this case the last row should not appear.

How can i achieve this in postgresql?

Comment: You should probably use the unlimited `TEXT` type for `anschrift` instead of `VARCHAR(N)`. Business rules like size limits should not be hard coded in data schemas, and there is no performance or storage size advantage to the limit. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like `WHERE erstelldatum = MAX(DATE)` but that doesn't work. You can use a sub-query to get the newest date.

```
SELECT *
FROM Kundendaten
WHERE erstelldatum = (
  SELECT MAX(erstelldatum) FROM Kundendaten
);
```

[(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67860/2/0)

Postgres will optimize that subquery so it is only run once, but you'll want to make sure `erstelldatum` is indexed.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the indexing hint! :)